# SKPaymentTransactionObserver - transaction fail

Tags: ios, objective-c, transactions, in-app-purchase

I am working on an app with in-app-purchase up to the transaction part.

I have a `purchaseViewController` to call up `getProductInfo` while launch:

```
-(void)getProductInfo: (CC3DeviceCameraOverlayUIViewController *) viewController
{
    _homeViewController = viewController;

    if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                      initWithProductIdentifiers:
                                      [NSSet setWithObject:self.productID]];
        request.delegate = self;

        [request start];
    }
    else
        _productDescription.text =
        @"Please enable In App Purchase in Settings";
}
```

which is successful. Then I have a button to call `buyProduct`:

```
- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender {

        SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
    if(_myQueue == nil) {
        _myQueue =  [SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue];
    }
        [_myQueue addPayment:payment];
    NSLog(@"buyproduct happening %@", _product.localizedTitle);
}
```

which also successful because I see the NSLog and the product title. 
But after this, I always get a `transaction failed!` when the purchasing process up to

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
//                [self unlockFeature];
                NSLog(@"Transaction purchased");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                if (_product.downloadable) {
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
                }
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                if (transaction.downloads) {
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];
                    NSLog(@"Transaction downloading now...");
                } else {
                    // unlock features
                    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                    NSLog(@"Transaction finish");
                }
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

What seems to be wrong and how can I debug this part? Is there a way for me to clear previous transaction test or check if there is any pending transaction interfere with the current test? I am still testing it in sandbox mode. The error was thrown in a quite immediate manner that give me the impression that it did not really go through Apple server and the transaction error happen locally, some sort of previous transaction test conflict or something that I still yet to find out.

One more point to mention is that I am purchasing non-consumable item, which if transaction successful, it will trigger the download(I hope.).

Comment: Can you give some more code-- how are you obtaining products? Are you getting the Apple prompt/alerts about buying the product?

Comment: @ChrisPrince I edited my code above.

Comment: Would it be a problem if I add my `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];` in `appDelegate` and have all other codes above in `purchaseViewController`?

Comment: 1) from my last question: are you getting apple prompts about buying the product? 2) how do you know getProductInfo is successful? Adding your transaction observer in the app delegate should be fine. The updatedTransaction method will need to be there as well.

Comment: 1)If you are talking about Apple get me to sign in with my account and asking me if I want to buy the item for xxx amount, Yes. 2)because I got the info back from iTuneConnect showing the title and the item description in `NSLog` and that at the same time activate my buy button.